# Architecture for REST API, web app and mobile apps that supports Single SignOn?

Tags: rest, architecture, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to find an answer to this question for a quite a while so I ask from you guys.

I'm building a image gallery that currently has Spring REST back-end. I'm currently working on SPA web application and I want the users to be able to log into the application with my image gallery credentials or Facebook account. I also want this SSO option to be available later in mobile app.

The back-end would contain all the business logic, data and user account information.

I think I have two options:

1. Make the back-end responsible for the sign-on process. Front-end would redirect to a page hosted by back-end where user could sign-in using my image gallery credentials or Facebook account.
2. Make the front-end responsible for the sign-on process and implement OAuth2 in the back-end. This would make my back-end work like Facebook's API.

If I go with option 1, can I still somehow develop native mobile app later that could use this setup for login? I also have not seen this kind of a setup because usually web pages offer login with their own credentials without leaving the page so I wonder if this is really a option?

If I go with option 2, how does my back-end know that the user has successfully authenticated over Facebook? Front-end could send a cookie that it got from Facebook with the request but I don't see how the back-end could verify that cookie since it did not issue it.

Is either of these options a reasonable way to implement such a project? Or is there some other options that I have not figured out?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is much point in implementing scenario 2) with OAuth 2.0. The whole point of OAuth2 is to provide end users with a mechanism that allows them to authorise what the application can or can't do (see third-party apps in Facebook).